# Get the max date within a group and fill the NaN rows of the group with max date

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as below.

```
key         date_from           date_to 
176785  21-04-2016 15:46    04-05-2016 15:39    
176785  01-05-2016 00:00        NaN
100000  10-05-2018 20:29    30-01-2019 09:35    
100000  01-06-2018 00:00    30-06-2018 00:00    
100000  01-07-2018 00:00    31-07-2018 00:00    
100000  01-08-2018 00:00    31-08-2018 00:00    
100000  01-09-2018 00:00    30-09-2018 00:00    
100000  01-10-2018 00:00    31-10-2018 00:00    
100000  01-11-2018 00:00    30-11-2018 00:00    
100000  01-12-2018 00:00    31-12-2018 00:00    
100000  01-01-2019 00:00          Nan
```

I need to fill the NaN values with the max date_to within the group.

I am expecting the output dataframe as follows.

```
key         date_from           date_to 
176785  21-04-2016 15:46    04-05-2016 15:39    
176785  01-05-2016 00:00    04-05-2016 15:39
100000  10-05-2018 20:29    30-01-2019 09:35    
100000  01-06-2018 00:00    30-06-2018 00:00    
100000  01-07-2018 00:00    31-07-2018 00:00    
100000  01-08-2018 00:00    31-08-2018 00:00    
100000  01-09-2018 00:00    30-09-2018 00:00    
100000  01-10-2018 00:00    31-10-2018 00:00    
100000  01-11-2018 00:00    30-11-2018 00:00    
100000  01-12-2018 00:00    31-12-2018 00:00    
100000  01-01-2019 00:00    30-01-2019 09:35
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for Series with same size like original filled by `max`:

```
df['date_to'] = df['date_to'].fillna(df.groupby('key')['date_to'].transform('max'))
```